# how to use & for sudo

Tags: linux, shell

I know if I put `&` at the end of application at the terminal, it will run in the background and terminal still can receive commands, for example:

```
howchen@host:~
-> cutecom&
[1] 17269
howchen@host:~
```

it can pop up `cutecom` application. However, I need run this application with root, I can NOT input as:

```
howchen@host:~
-> su cutecom&
```

if I never run some applications with `su` before, it will output like:

```
howchen@host:~
-> su cutecom&
[1] 17404
howchen@host:~
-> No passwd entry for user 'cutecom'
```

Comment: The error `No passwd entry for user 'cutecom'` indicates that you are using wrong syntax of `su`. If you want to run it with root, use `sudo cutecom`; if you want to use the `su` utility, use `su root -c cutecom`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While all the answers about `sudo` vs `su` are correct, they don't address the `&` part of the question.

The issue with trying to do something like `sudo somecommand &` is that it backgrounds `sudo` (which happens before it gets a chance to prompt for the password). You want to background `somecommand` instead. The `&` is a shell operator, so it takes precedence and operates before invoking any commands. This needs to be changed so that `sudo` happens first, and then the backgrounding.
Since `&` is a shell operator, we need to have sudo launch another shell to be able to handle it. The way to do this is something such as the following:

```
sudo sh -c 'somecommand &'
```

This way you'll get the `sudo` prompt for the password, and then sudo will launch `sh -c 'somecommand &'`, so the backgrounding will be handled by a new shell instead of the current one.

Answer (score 7):

As @Kiwy said, `su cutecom` means that you are trying to change current user to the user `cutecom`.

If you want to su to root and run the command cutecom, the correct syntax is

`su -c cutecom`

This will require you to enter the root password.

As @kiwy said, it's far more common to use `sudo` to run commands as root. It can be setup allow you to run any command as another user, and either not require a password, or allow you to use your own password instead of the root password.

Answer (score 2):

If, for some reason, you absolutely have to use su instead of sudo, the following should help.   I'm using bash for these examples, any shell that has job control capabilities should behave similarly, as far as I've ever experienced.  Run the command as folows:

```
su root -c cutecom
```

Once cutecom has started, hit Control-Z.  In most shells, and most environments I've ever been in, Control-Z is the Suspend Sequence.  The shell should respond back with something similar to:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 su root -c cutecom
```

And it'll return you back to a shell prompt.  Assuming that the previous response started with [1], enter the following command:

```
bg %1
```

This will put job #1 into the background, print something similar to the following:

```
[1]+ su root -c cutecom &
```

and return you to the prompt.

If you ever need to bring it back into the foreground (this also works for regular jobs started with an &), you can type:

```
fg %1
```

If you need a listing of all backgrounded and suspended jobs, you can use the jobs command:

```
jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 su root -c dullcom
[2]-  Running                 su root -c cutecom &
```

Answer (score 0):

The  command `su` is used to authenticate as `root` by default or as the name of the user pass as first argument. For example `su foo` will try to authenticate you as the `foo` user.

The command `sudo` is used to run a command against the root context without being `root` user.

[image: explanation of sudo command through the "Make me a sandwich" example]

If you want to execute a command as root use :
`sudo mycommand`
if you want to run a background command as `root` just try:
`sudo mycommand&`

Sometime this will not work, I don't know why (I presume because of system call that need root access too) then you can connect as root using :
`sudo -s` and then type `mycommand&`

if you want to authenticate as root try :
`su`

But if sudo is available on your system, there's a few chance that `su` will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo bash
what_ever_command &
exit
```